# Sql queries using foreign key relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have made a Library management system. I am trying to print the student issue book, but I am facing problems with the SQL query.Below is the User.php code for printing the issue book . I am also uploading the Database for easy referall. Please help.

User.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['var'];
include ("connection.php");
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>User </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php echo "<h2>" . $username . "</h2>";
?>
<table class="w3-table-all w3-card-4">
<tr>
    <th>Book Name </th>
  <th>Issue Date</th>
  <th>Submit Date</th>
</tr>
    <?php
        $query="select isbn, issuedt, submitdt from passbook INNER JOIN usertable on usertable.username='$username' where passbook.id=(usertable.username= '$username') ";
        $result= mysqli_query($sql, $query);
        while($row=$result-> fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo "<tr><td>". $row["isbn"]. "</td><td>". $row["issuedt"]. "</td><td>". $row["submitdt"]."</td><tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";              
    ?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the database of the Library management system.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.7.9
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Apr 29, 2018 at 03:31 PM
-- Server version: 10.1.31-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.2.3

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `library`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `library` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `library`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `book`
--

CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `isbn` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `bookname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `bookid` int(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- RELATIONSHIPS FOR TABLE `book`:
--   `bookid`
--       `type` -> `bookid_type`
--

--
-- Dumping data for table `book`
--

INSERT INTO `book` (`isbn`, `bookname`, `author`, `bookid`) VALUES
('100', 'harry potter', 'j k rowling', 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `passbook`
--

CREATE TABLE `passbook` (
  `pid` int(200) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(200) NOT NULL,
  `isbn` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `issuedt` date NOT NULL,
  `submitdt` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- RELATIONSHIPS FOR TABLE `passbook`:
--   `user_id`
--       `usertable` -> `id`
--   `isbn`
--       `book` -> `isbn`
--

--
-- Dumping data for table `passbook`
--

INSERT INTO `passbook` (`pid`, `user_id`, `isbn`, `issuedt`, `submitdt`) VALUES
(2, 0, '100', '2018-04-04', '2018-04-26');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `type`
--

 CREATE TABLE `type` (
 `bookid_type` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
 -- RELATIONSHIPS FOR TABLE `type`:
--

--
-- Dumping data for table `type`
--

INSERT INTO `type` (`bookid_type`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Magic');

 -- --------------------------------------------------------

 --
-- Table structure for table `usertable`
--

CREATE TABLE `usertable` (
  `id` int(200) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `dateofbirth` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- RELATIONSHIPS FOR TABLE `usertable`:
--

--
-- Dumping data for table `usertable`
--

INSERT INTO `usertable` (`id`, `name`, `username`, `password`, `dateofbirth`) VALUES
(0, 'Priyanka', 'priyanka', 'priyanka', '2018-03-04'),
(1, 'puru', 'puru', 'puru', '2018-03-05');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `book`
--
ALTER TABLE `book`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`isbn`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `bookid` (`bookid`);

--
-- Indexes for table `passbook`
--
ALTER TABLE `passbook`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`pid`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `isbn_number` (`isbn`),
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `type`
--
ALTER TABLE `type`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`bookid_type`);

--
-- Indexes for table `usertable`
--
 ALTER TABLE `usertable`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `passbook`
--
ALTER TABLE `passbook`
  MODIFY `pid` int(200) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `book`
--
ALTER TABLE `book`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `book_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`bookid`) REFERENCES `type` 
 (`bookid_type`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `passbook`
--
ALTER TABLE `passbook`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `passbook_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES 
`usertable` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `passbook_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`isbn`) REFERENCES `book` 
(`isbn`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

The database is related in this way :- usertable has id as primary key.Book has isbn as primary key, bookid as foreign key. Type has bookid as primary key. Passbook has isbn as foreign key, uid as primary key.
I want to display the passbook where the book name will be shown along with the issue date and submit date. So i have to fetch two data from two different tables, the book name from the boo table using the isbn number, and the userid from the usertable which I have to run against the passbook table to find the relevant entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be more like...

```
$query="select passbook.isbn, issuedt, submitdt, bookname
    from passbook 
    INNER JOIN usertable on usertable.id=passbook.user_id 
    INNER JOIN book on passbook.isbn = book.isbn
    where usertable.username= '$username' ";
```

This links the user_id on passbook to the usertable id and does the selection of which user to limit with in the where clause instead.

Adding in a link to the books table means linking the passbook isbn to the book isbn field.  The one thing to remember is that isbn is then on two tables being selected, so remember to add this to the fields selected (I've used the one from passbook, although they are both the same).

(Although you should be using prepared statements to select bu username.)

Comment: This shows the book isbn not the book name. How can I join the books table so that in the final output the book name is shown? Please help.

Comment: I've updated the select, you will just have to update the fields you display.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Worked like a charm . Keep up the good work :)